# If I pass a ndarray view to a function I can find its base but how can I find the slice?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, view, slice, radix

numpy slicing e.g. `S=np.s_[1:-1]; V=A[1:-1]`, produces a view of the underlying array. I can find this underlying array by `V.base`.  If I pass such a view to a function, e.g.

```
def f(x):
    return x.base
```

then `f(V) == A`. But how can I find the slice information `S`? I am looking for an attribute something like `base` containing information on the slice that created this view. I would like to be able to write a function to which I can pass a view of an array and return another view of the same array calculated from the view. E.g. I would like to be able to shift the view to the right or left of a one dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the slicing information is not stored anywhere, but you might be able to deduce it from attributes of the view and base.

For example:

```
In [156]: x=np.arange(10)
In [157]: y=x[3:]
In [159]: y.base
Out[159]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [160]: y.data
Out[160]: <memory at 0xb1a16b8c>
In [161]: y.base.data
Out[161]: <memory at 0xb1a16bf4>
```

I like the `__array_interface__` value  better:

```
In [162]: y.__array_interface__['data']
Out[162]: (163056924, False)
In [163]: y.base.__array_interface__['data']
Out[163]: (163056912, False)
```

So `y` databuffer starts 12 bytes beyond `x`.  And since `y.itemsize` is 4, this means that the slicing start is `3`.

```
In [164]: y.shape
Out[164]: (7,)
In [165]: x.shape
Out[165]: (10,)
```

And comparing the shapes, I deduce that the slice stop is `None` (the end).

For 2d arrays, or stepped slicing you'd have to look at the `strides` as well.

But in practice it is probably easier, and safer, to pass the slicing object (tuple, slice, etc) to your function, rather than deduce it from the results.

```
In [173]: S=np.s_[1:-1]
In [174]: S
Out[174]: slice(1, -1, None)
In [175]: x[S]
Out[175]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

That is, pass `S` itself, rather than deduce it. I've never seen it done before.

Comment: I think just passing S would defeat the purpose but you provided what I needed for a somewhat intuitive  5 line solution in 1d. It seems odd to me if this use of slicing really wasn't anticipated in numpy.